# highslide and highchart

Tags: highcharts, highslide

am building highcharts and highstock and i will put them in to a page as small charts then to click on it so it will expand (highslide) but the code is not working

this is one of the charts 
http://www.nourhammoury.com/silvercot.php

am adding the code like in this example here http://www.highcharts.com/studies/with-highslide.htm but its not working at all

can anyone help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to show complete slide show in high slide ... But its can possible I achieved solution that is using zoom in css initially i put zoom in for all divs and when click on div its zoom out. And also write some slideshow event manually.

Sample code in :  http://sdrv.ms/17sUIR7

Answer (score 1):

Please see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/GqhEX/ Study the js code thoroughly.

Note that the Highslide files must be included in the head section of the page.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://highcharts.com/highslide/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.config.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css"/>
```

Comment: i did add these but still not showing , somthin wrong with the second part of the code (down, the first part is ok but the second one crash the chart. can u explain more please thanks

Comment: See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hstSH/2/ Note the code at the start and the end of the chart.