# HighCharts in HighSlide

Tags: highcharts, highslide

Could you please provide sloution Highchart in Highslide.

In my case i have 10  josn object(highchart objects). I have to show in chart like below example with thumbstrip (http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-horizontal-strip-next-onImageClick.html).

In that instated  of using Image i have to use josn object.

All slider features like navigation ,next ,previous and slideshow.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you attempted to code this yourself?

Comment: Have you seend related topic ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173339/highslide-and-highchart

Comment: Yeah, I seen the above example. I achieved solution that is using zoom in css initially i put zoom in for all divs and when click on div its zoom out. And also write some slideshow event manually.