# Highchart Get Function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to change my point clickable chart to popup like this:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

I want to grab this code to my plot option highchart:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
        $(".ajax").colorbox();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Other Content Types</h2>
    <p><a class='ajax' href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/main/chartleveldata" title="iDetails">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
```

And my plot option highchart is like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    candlestick: {
        lineColor: '#404048'
    },
    series: {
        animation: 
        {
            duration: 3000
        },
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    //window.open('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/main/chartleveldata?due_date='+this.category+'&dsp=<?php echo $dspray;?>', '', 'top=200, menubar=no, left=500, width=340, height=200, directories=no, location=no, status=no,');
                    $(".ajax").colorbox();
                    location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/main/chartleveldata?due_date='+this.category+'&dsp=<?php echo $dspray;?>';
                }
        }
    }
},
```

I have been set the header and style like the code which I want to grab, but it show nothing change.

Do I make a mistake?

Comment: Open a empty `div` in popup first and then render hightchart in it. Or open the `div` which contains highchart and do a `redraw`

Comment: Sorry, may you give me an explanation more about it @Jashwant ?

Comment: Have you seen somehing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173339/highslide-and-highchart